How to use biometrics with an existing OAuth system
My mobile app has this (fairly common) authentication user experience:

user signs in with email and password
user is prompted to enable biometrics for faster access next time
when user returns to app after a time of inactivity

if they enabled biometrics, they are given the biometric challenge and then granted full access to the app
if they did not enable biometrics, they need to log in again with email and password


if user chooses to explicitly log out, then next time they are treated as a new user (go to point 1)

I'm stuck on how to securely implement step 3.1.
My app is written in React Native and using react-native-biometrics and our backend is using django-oauth-toolkit and django rest framework. There's a diagram in the docs illustrating the intended use, but to briefly summarise:

When enabling biometrics, app generates a key pair on device
App registers the public key with the backend
When a user returns to the app, app prompts for biometrics
App sends a signed payload to the backend
Backend verifies signature using stored public key

So far so good, but what happens next? Once the user has successfully passed biometric authentication, how to I make them signed in on the device? I had thought of storing the user's refresh token on the server and returning that in point 5 above, but that amounts to storing unhashed credentials on the server, which is obviously not OK.
Am I thinking about this right? Do I need to find some way to mint a new access/refresh token?
